# Can the NSA/FBI Recover Encrypted iPhone Contents by Decapping the Chips?

Tags: iphone, nsa

The NSA/FBI certainly has the ability to reliably decap microprocessors, surely has impressive microscopes that can map out those chips and insert probes, and probably has access to many of these chip's inner-workings.

What is stopping them from decapping the iPhone, physically getting around the security features built into the software, and cracking its security?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I'm curious about this too -- I've seen a lot of people say "All the FBI has to do is decap the chip and read the flash with an electron microscope", but how feasible is that without damaging the chip and destroying the key? Why kind of success rate would a procedure like this have? How commonly is it done?

Comment: [FBI claims they may be able to break into the phone without Apple's help](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/03/21/fbi-requests-court-delay-iphone-encryption-motion-citing-new-unlock-method), perhaps that's what they're going to try?